# unable to set admin account for opencart

Tags: mysql, sql, opencart

I am trying this code to setup my admin account for admin panel in opencart store on my local machine
from http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/opencart/346-add-admin-via-db

```
INSERT INTO oc_user VALUES 
(9999,1, 'admin123', '21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3', '',
'firstname', 'lastname', 'email@example.com', '',
'0.0.0.0',1,CURDATE());
```

& I got the error

> ## 1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

please tell me whats the problem with that code my Opencart version is Version 1.5.6.1

Answer (score 0):

The error is very clear you specified to many columns (for example table has 11 column and you try to insert 12 values)

Get column list first:

```
SELECT * FROM oc_user LIMIT 1;
```

Then use `INSERT INTO tabname(column_list)`  and set corresponding names (you may need to remove some data):

```
INSERT INTO oc_user(col1, col2, col3, ...)
VALUES (9999,1, 'admin123', '21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3', '',
'firstname', 'lastname', 'email@example.com', '',
'0.0.0.0',1,CURDATE());
```